# How to us Ajax Modalpopupextender in usercontrol?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Hi i am studying asp.net webforms and i am now creating usercontrols and trying to use ajaxtoolkit.

On my  user Control i copy this code from Ajax-MessageBox [Dotnetgurus](http://dotnetgurus.net/post/2009/09/15/ASPNet-MessageBox-with-AJAX.aspx)

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnD" runat="server" Text="" Style="display: none" Width="0" Height="0" /> 
<AjaxControls:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeMsg" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnD"
            PopupControlID="pnlMsg" PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlMsgHD" BackgroundCssClass="mpBg"
            DropShadow="true" OkControlID="btnOK">
        </AjaxControls:ModalPopupExtender>
```

and i want to add Modalpopupextender in it but when i drag it to my btnD an error message box shows.

```
The operation could not be completed. Invalid FORMATETC structure 
Warning 1   Generation of designer file failed: Unknown server tag 'AjaxControls:ModalPopupExtender'.
```

There is no > symbol also when  i drag new button on the form because of that i cant add extender.

Thanks in Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add Ajaxtoolkit.dll on your Reference
2. Reset your Toolbox and Add again Ajaxtoolkit.
3. Build / Rebuild your Solution

[Ajaxtoolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx)

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="cc1" %>
```

Regards

Answer (score 4):

You need to register the AjaxControlToolKit.dll either in web.config or in your UserControl like:

```
        <pages validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="cc1" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
```

or in UserControl like:
`<%@ Register tagprefix="tagprefix"
   namespace="namespace"
   assembly="assembly" %>`